# Decoding gzip-ed response bodies with url-retrieve

Tags: http, emacs, elisp

For an Emacs extension, I'd like to retrieve data over HTTP. I'm not particularly fond of the idea of shelling out to things like `wget`, `curl`, or `w3m` to be able to do that, so I'm using the `url-retrieve` function.

One of the HTTP servers i'm talking to happens to ignore `Accept-Encoding` headers and insists on always sending out its data with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

As a result of that, and of the fact that `url-retrieve` doesn't automatically decode response bodies, the buffer `url-retrieve` will present me will contain binary gzip data.

I'm looking for a way to decode the response body, preferably chunk by chunk, as the data arrives. Is there a way to instruct `url-retrieve` to do this for me?

Decoding the response all at once, once it completely arrived, would also be acceptable, but I'd rather avoid all the fubar involved in creating an asynchronous subprocess running gzip, piping parts of the response I got to that, and reading the decoded chunks back in - I'd be looking for some library function here.

Comment: Emacs obviously has gzip built in, as you can open up gzipped files, edit them, and save them transparently.  The question is ... where is this hook, and the answer is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks, John. While I was aware of being able to open gzipped files, it really didn't occur to me that this might be related, but obviously it is. From opening a .gz file on disk, looking at `*Messages*`, and searching my elisp directories for whatever I got, I figured out the code implementing that is `jka-cmpr-hook.el` and/or `jka-compr.el`. It seems likely that this problem is easy to solve with once of the functions provided by those. `with-auto-compression-mode` seems most promising right now.

Comment: sort of off-topic, but do you happen to know if url-retrieve can handle https?

Comment: Why not try it and see for yourself? `(url-retrieve "https://google.com/" #'(lambda (status) (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))))`

Answer (score 4):

What `auto-compression-mode` does is run gzip on the file to be uncompressed. See for example [`jka-compr-insert-file-contents`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#P7Qrbt91wTk/lisp/jka-compr.el&q=jka-compr-insert-file-contents&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc) in `jka-compr.el`. So if you're going to use `auto-compression-mode` to do the uncompression, you're going to need to write the response to a file first. For example, something like this:

```
(defun uncompress-callback (status)
  (let ((filename (make-temp-file "download" nil ".gz")))
    (search-forward "\n\n")               ; Skip response headers.
    (write-region (point) (point-max) filename)
    (with-auto-compression-mode
      (find-file filename))))

(url-retrieve "http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/allpackages?format=txt.gz"
              #'uncompress-callback)
```

(If you don't want to create a temporary file, you'll have do your own subprocess management, but it's not as tricky as you imply in your question.)

Comment: if you're using `url-retrieve-synchronously` you can just switch to the buffer and then run that callback, you won't need to accept the status argument at all (I would added `&optional`)